# Why does my > while loop keeps repeating infinitely?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is part of my code, when used, it prints "I'm sorry, your order is over £25 pounds, please correct this." an infinite amount of times. What can I do to fix this?

```
    main = input("Now please enter your choice: A, B or C.\n")
    while True:  
      if main == "A":
       main = "Roast Duck"
       amount2 = input("How many portions of Roast Duck would you like?")
       totalPrice = totalPrice + 5.80*float(amount2)
       while True:
           if totalPrice > 25:
              print("I'm sorry, your order is over £25 pounds, please correct this.")
        else:
            break
    products.append("Roast Duck ("+amount2+" portions) .")
    break
```

Comment: indentation error: the `else` belongs to the `while` statement, not `if`

Comment: but even without the indent error, the condition never changes, so if totalPrice > 25 it just prints the error message forever (the indent if off so we cannot know for sure)

Comment: What value does `totalPrice` have when your code begins to run?

Comment: It starts with totalPrice = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off of your question, I'm guessing you would want your code to look like this:

```
main = input("Now please enter your choice: A, B or C.\n")
while True:  
    if main == "A":
        main = "Roast Duck"
        amount2 = input("How many portions of Roast Duck would you like?")
        totalPrice = totalPrice + 5.80*float(amount2)
        while (totalPrice > 25):
            print("I'm sorry, your order is over £25 pounds, please correct this.")
            amount2 = input("How many portions of Roast Duck would you like?")
            totalPrice = totalPrice + 5.80*float(amount2)
    else:
        break
    products.append("Roast Duck ("+amount2+" portions) .")
    break
```

#### The logic:

If someone selects `A`, they'll be prompted to choose a number of portions. Then, if the price exceeds £25, it will display the message and loop back to have the user input a new amount. Once the amount falls under £25, the inner `while` loop will quit and the portions of roast duck will be appended to `products`, then the code will break out of the outer `while` loop.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want it to do!

Comment: As it stands, this will continue to add to totalPrice without ever setting it lower than 25 (if it was greater than 25 to begin with). If the goal is to simply set the `totalPrice` equal to the amount of duck*money you are buying, you should use `totalPrice = 5.80*float(amount2)`. Assuming you have other things to buy though, this will not keep a running total.

Comment: Would it be easier if I post more than one portion of my code, because there are more items to buy?

Comment: I have used the above code ^^^ and it helps massively (thank you!), however it keeps repeating the "How many portions of Roast Duck would you like?" question, even when the user corrects their error and enters an input which means it is less than £25

Comment: @AlarisHart I would just advise you go through what was written and think about how it works. `totalPrice = totalPrice + 5.80*float(amount2)` adds the current value of totalPrice to 5.80*duck. If it is > 25, of course it will never become lower unless you have negative duck. SO is meant to be used for learning as opposed to a code writing service. If you get stuck again, you can always ask another question - though I would try to explain your issues and thought process a bit better the next time. It shows you put in the effort.

Comment: @AlarisHart please look to my most recent edit of my own answer. I don't know how to format on SO very well.

Comment: @AlarisHart That's because you never reset the value of `totalPrice`; once it exceeds £25, it never goes back down. You could add in a line to remove the most recent amount added in the event it exceeds £25 -- something like `totalPrice = totalPrice - 5.80 * float(amount2)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is completed and working now

Answer (score 2):

You never break out of this loop:

```
while True:
    if totalPrice > 25:
       print("I'm sorry, your order is over £25 pounds, please correct this.")
```

Also, your final break is not inside of the first `while` loop

Below is how you might structure your looping of buying duck:

```
runningTotal = 0
priceOfDuck = 5.8*float(input()) 
while runningTotal + priceOfDuck > 25 : 
     priceOfDuck = 5.8*float(input()) 
runningTotal = runningTotal + priceOfDuck
```

Comment: even if it was, it would be a potential infinite loop. And if it isn't (the indentation is off anyway) it's a 100% sure infinite loop.

Comment: So it can never be fixed?

Comment: @AlarisHart The way you currently have it, you need to ask for new input/change totalPrice, because if it is > 25 it will continue through that loop forever as you don't adjust the value.

Comment: How do I ask for the new amount? This is my first time on python, so I am awfully confused.

Comment: @AlarisHart Like @freginold wrote, you can ask the user for more input inside of blocks of code where you know `TotalPrice > 25`. So after validating that with the `if` you can add an `input()` call. S/he already wrote an equivalent solution to this so you can just look at that.

Comment: @AlarisHart After looking at the loop more closely, it's not actually correct - though it does illustrate the technical aspect fine.